# Not able to run global modules installed with 'n'

Tags: node.js, npm

Have installed Node version manager 'n'.

Installed 'mocha' using

```
n npm 0.6.4 install mocha -g.
```

Now when I try to access it using

```
mocha -R spec
```

I get an error 'command not found'. Is there some option I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'n' is the version manager and not the package manager. In other words, you use 'n' to install different versions of NodeJS. You'll use npm to install packages like mocha.

Type `n 0.6.4` will install NodeJS version 0.6.4 and set it in your path.

Type `npm install mocha -g` will install mocha as global module.

Run both the above commands in order, then you'll find mocha in your path.